# Why is a pointer getting set to (nil) when passed to a function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm encountering segmentation faults while trying to get a thread hander simulator working in C. I define the following structures:

```
typedef struct queue_t {
    struct green_t *front, *rear;
} queue_t;

typedef struct green_cond_t {
    struct queue_t *queue;
} green_cond_t;
```

in green.o i have functions for a green condition (most importantly showing how I initialize a `green_cond_t` struct):

```
void green_cond_init(green_cond_t *cond) {
    cond = (green_cond_t *) malloc(sizeof(green_cond_t));
    cond->queue = (queue_t *) malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
    cond->queue->front = cond->queue->rear = NULL;
}

void green_cond_wait(green_cond_t *cond) {
    green_t *susp = running;
    enqueue(cond->queue, susp);
    running = dequeue(ready);
    swapcontext(susp->context, running->context);
}

void green_cond_signal(green_cond_t *cond) {
    //check pointer reference
    printf("queue pointer in green_cond_signal: %p\n", cond->queue);
    if (dequeue(cond->queue) == NULL) return; //assuming segfault happens here...
    green_t *init = dequeue(cond->queue);
    enqueue(ready, init);
}
```

in test.c:

```
int flag = 0;
green_cond_t cond;

void * test(void *arg) {
    int id = *(int *) arg;
    int loop = 4;
    while (loop > 0) {
        if (flag == id) {
            printf("thread %d: %d\n", id, loop);
            loop--;
            flag = (id + 1) % 2;
            //check pointer reference
            printf("queue pointer in test: %p\n", &cond.queue);
            green_cond_signal(&cond);
        } else {
            green_cond_wait(&cond);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    green_cond_init(&cond);

    green_t g0, g1;
    int a0 = 0;
    int a1 = 1;

    green_create(&g0, test, &a0);
    green_create(&g1, test, &a1);

    green_join(&g0, NULL);
    green_join(&g1, NULL);
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the output from running test.c:

```
thread 0: 4
queue pointer in test: 0x5620b9f8c450
queue pointer in green_cond_signal: (nil)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555499f in dequeue ()
(gdb) back
#0  0x000055555555499f in dequeue ()
#1  0x0000555555554d5c in green_cond_signal ()
#2  0x0000555555554e22 in test ()
#3  0x0000555555554b04 in green_thread ()
#4  0x00007ffff7a3c6b0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

for some reason the `cond.queue` pointer is being set to nil on calling `green_cond_signal()` the first time and I just can't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the the address of a `green_cond_t` to `green_cond_init`, but then you overwrite the value of the pointer you passed in:

```
cond = (green_cond_t *) malloc(sizeof(green_cond_t));
```

This means you're initializing a dynamically allocated structure, not the global one.  So when the function returns, the global `cond` still contains a NULL pointer from its implicit initialization.

Remove the above `malloc` call from `green_cond_init` and the global `cond` will be properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
printf("queue pointer in test: %p\n", &cond.queue);
```

you print the *address* of `cond.queue` (the &-operator works on the whole construct, you probably meant to do: `(&cond)->queue`, which is the same as `cond.queue`.

And here you print the *content*:

```
printf("queue pointer in green_cond_signal: %p\n", cond->queue);
```

which was already a `NULL` pointer before calling.
Use

```
printf("queue pointer in test: %p\n", cond.queue);
```

to get a meaningful result.